# Simple VBA to Select a Range from First .Find Value?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to locate a value within column "A" then select from that address to the first blank row encountered. Here is what I have, but Set f isn't working. My Set c works and returns $A$32, which is the correct address. What am I missing?

```
With Workbooks("MyBook").Sheets("Mysheet")
    Set c = .Range("$A:$A").Find("Red Car").Offset(2, 0)
    Set f = .Range(c.Address & Range("A").End(xlDown).Row)
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and check first that the search term is found

```
With Workbooks("MyBook").Sheets("Mysheet")
    Set c = .Range("$A:$A").Find("Red Car")
    If Not c Is Nothing Then Set f = Range(c.Offset(2, 0), c.Offset(2, 0).End(xlDown))
End With
```

Comment: On which line? How have you declared c and f?

Comment: error occurs at Setf = Range(c, c.End(xlDown)). c and f are declared in-line. im not using option explicit. should i be?

Comment: Yes it is good practice. Put `Dim c As Range, f As Range` at the top of your code, just after the sub line and then try it.

Comment: still returns a type mistmatch. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure. I have corrected the code above but I don't think it corrects anything that was causing the problem. Have you added Option Explicit?

Comment: By any chance are you trying to call f with a msgbox or something of the sort?  Are you positive the error is occurring on the same line as `If Not c...`

Comment: Whoops! When debuging, i was using Debug.Print f, which was throwing the error. I changed to Debug.Print f.Address and now i see it works. THANKS SJR!

Comment: Glad it works. Note that if you don't have any other entries in column A f will be the whole column.

Answer (score 1):

`Removed Code`

You are just trying to assign `Range($A$32 & LastRow)`.  Without adding the : (colon) and column letter (A), it cannot properly assign the range to F.  Try this code and see if it works now.

Comment: Use @SJRs solution.  I wrote this on my phone and may have missed something.  The logic itself is there, but the code may not be.